# Magento cron jobs fail because of attempts to write to the wrong part of the filesystem

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron, cronjobs, filesystem

I noticed for a while that although I could run the commands in my crontab just fine, they would not run from cron itself; when I looked at magento.cron.log, I found lines like this:

```
Directory "var/locks/" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
```

I noticed that `var/locks` in my Magento installation directory had all of the correct permissions, and it was full of lock-files, but just from when I would manually run the cron jobs; also, `~/var` was mostly locked down in my shared-hosting setup, and the only sub-directories I could see are the per-site directories (I can't even enumerate sub-directories of `~/var`, only guess at what the names are, and I can tell that in particular there is no `~/var/locks`).

Prepending each Magento cron job with a command to switch to the Magento installation directory (using an absolute path) worked; for example, if my username were `user` and Magento were installed in `~/magento`, then the relevant command would change from

```
* * * * * php /home/user/magento/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/user/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

to

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/magento && php /home/user/magento/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/user/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

(Here, the correct `php` executable was in my `$PATH`, which I had explicitly set near the top of my crontab.)

Why does Magento try to write lock-files to `~/var/locks` rather than `var/locks` under its own installation directory? I'm currently running Magento 2.3.6-p1.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be a good idea to limit how much each cron job has to do by breaking them up, as detailed here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26809#issuecomment-588267706

The actual crontab line I now use (again assuming the username is `user` and Magento installation directory is `~/magento`) is

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/magento && chronic flock -w 0 /tmp/crongroup_default php /home/user/magento/bin/magento cron:run --group="default" --bootstrap="standaloneProcessStarted=1" 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/user/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

and there are lines for each cron group, as I found in my admin area, with the less-used groups (like `consumers`) only runnning every 30 minutes; the system-wide `/tmp` directory is writable on my system, but you could use `/home/user/tmp` or even `/home/user/magento/var/locks`.

(Okay, there is one more thing: Nexcess regularly prepends `/usr/sbin/relax`, a proprietary shell-script, before any bare invocation of `php` at the start of a cron job, probably to mitigate the impact of frequent invocations of `php` on shared hosting, and I decided to put that before `chronic` when I changed my crontab line to include that; the problems in the main post long pre-dated such changes.)